# Change web project to class library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, csproj, webproject

Is there any way but copying the .cs files?

Changing the .csproj file? But how?

There is a related question, but I'm not satisfied with the answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546979/how-to-convert-web-application-project-to-class-library-project)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be satisfied with the answer, but it's still the right one and this is still a dupe I'm afraid.

Honestly, it would take no more than an hour to refactor.

Comment: It seems I *could* be changing the project file, but recreating the projects will probably be the fastest and most eye-friendly solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually edit the .proj file and remove the <ProjectTypeGuids> element.

You might also want to remove the other elements relating to IIS.  Do a compare on this .proj file and one from a properly set up class library.