# MVC3 Areas from other projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I hope this isn't too vague.

I am wanting to create an mvc project in which I can use in other projects. I am wondering whether I can do this with Areas. Although when trying it looks at the wrong folder for the views. Does any one know a way of doing this? or Is there a different method?

Comment: Possible Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656843/area-as-a-virtual-on-other-websites

Comment: Sorry when looking I didnt find that post. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out portable areas, I think its exactly what you are looking for.

http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider](https://github.com/mcintyre321/EmbeddedResourceVirtualPathProvider#readme) which works for MVC views and also other content files (e.g. js/css/aspx).