# How to create an ASP.NET MVC 3 control/component that can be reused by other applications

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reusability

I am required to deliver a component, inlcuding business logic and UI, to be used on a ASP.NET MVC 3 web site that is being developed by other company.

I know my way around ASP.NET WebForms server controls and how to package and distribute them to be reused across projects. I also have experience with MVC approach in general and some ASP.NET MVC experience. I did read over materials recommending use of HTML helpers and similar, but most of this deals with only UI reusability or reusability inside a single ASP.NET MVC project. I did not find any mentions of how to package and distribute such functionality for ASP.NET MVC.

The business logic is major part of this component. It is supposed to be a kind of wizard, which  progresses through a lot of steps and which would also work with database using Entity Framework and send an email to the user upon completion.

- How would I go about creating a control/component that encapsulates complex business logic and also renders its own UI/view output and that would be distributable in form of a standalone assembly? Is this even possible or only to some extend?
- Would this somehow be doable by wrapping model, view and controller inside an assembly?
- Or would it be better to approach this just as a complex model? If so, how would it be possible to connect the UI/view and controller to this component by the consumer of the component?

I also did see a couple of vendors out there, such as Telerik, who sell something along the lines of ASP.NET MVC controls/components, so I assume this is somehow possible to do.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656843/how-to-reuse-areas-controllers-views-models-routes-in-multiple-apps-or-websi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/11/14/how-to-call-controllers-in-external-assemblies-in-an-asp.net.aspx) tells how to call controllers from another assemblies.

To reuse only views, you can use [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/).

Comment: I'm currently using RazorGenerator to stick common views in our common library, and it really does the trick. You could wrap everything you are looking to do into a single assembly and be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to refer the [MVC Control ToolKit](http://mvccontrolstoolkit.codeplex.com/) Project page of CodePlex

Also see [ASP.Net MVC Sprite](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home) Project