# Incorrect routing with RegisterRoutes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why if I call:

```
http://localhost:55058/support/Faqs
```

I get this:

```
http://localhost:55058/Products/Faqs/Faq
```

with the following RegisterRoutes implementation? How can I get:

```
http://localhost:55058/Support/Faqs/Faq
```

Thanks.

```
public class SupportController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult FAQs()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Faq", "Faqs");
    }
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{filename}.html|js|css|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Products", // Route name
            "Products/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ProductName", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
         "Support", // Route name
         "Support/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Support", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
         );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );

}
```

Comment: what happens if you comment the first "Product" route and try the url???

Comment: It works fine but I need even the `Products` route to allow the `http://localhost:55058/Products/ProductName/Intro` URL to work

Comment: I think everything is working fine, just the line **return RedirectToAction("Faq", "Faqs");** is making some mess.. can you please write **return Content("TEST");** instead of that to check if i am right?

Comment: it works in the same way but the URL shown is `http://localhost:55058/Products/faqs/Faq` instead of `http://localhost:55058/Support/faqs/Faq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a bit more data its hard to tell - but it looks like you're kind of trying to use areas, but not actually using areas?

What's happening is your `RedirectToAction("Faq", "Faqs")` is matching all of your routes - so it picks the first one, in this case `Products`.

What's the difference between `"Products/{controller}/{action}"` and `"Support/{controller}/{action}"` routes? Are they coming from a different place? You're sending them both to the same controller, same action regardless of what the URL starts with - and that seems confusing.

If by going to /products/... you should get different results than /support/... you should look into [MVC Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

If they're supposed to get the **same results** which is what you have now - maybe you should consider removing those urls and just use the default?

Here's some additional resources on areas:

1. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2. From [Asp.net](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/asp-net-mvc-areasa-better-way-to-structure-the-application/)
3. From [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061153/mvc-areas-for-enterprise-good-or-bad)

**EDIT** From your comment:

To route: `http://localhost:55058/Products/ProductName/Download`

Update your routes like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Products", // Route name
            "Products/ProductName/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "ProductName", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
         "Support", // Route name
         "Support/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
         new { controller = "Support", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
         );
```

Comment: Hi Mark, yes I am trying to mimic areas. I send the `"Products/{controller}/{action}"` to the ProductNameController and the `"Support/{controller}/{action}"` to the SupportController...

Comment: Updated my answer - but I'm a bit confused by the route you want.  If you want: Products/Products (controller) / Index (action) ?  - Products/Products/action, I can change the routes to that.  And Support/Support/Action?  Support/Faqs/Faqs doesn't make sense in that context - because you're going to Support/Faqs (do you have a faqs controller)/Faq

Comment: The suggested solution makes the Products route to fail... We call it with the following actions `http://localhost:55058/Products/ProductName/Gallery`, `http://localhost:55058/Products/ProductName/Download`, etc.

Comment: I've updated the answer for the routes above - but what about http://localhost:55058/Support/Faqs/Faq.  Would that need to Goto the Faqs controller, or the Support controller?

Comment: We have a FaqsController with the `Faq` action

Comment: Not completely, `Products/ProductName/Downloads` does a `RedirectToAction("Download", "Download")` that is displayed as `http://localhost:55058/Support/Download` instead of `http://localhost:55058/Products/ProductName/Download`

Comment: Should: RedirectToAction("Download", "Download") being going to the ProductName Controller, Download Action?  If so - your redirect should be: RedirectToAction("Download") or RedirectToAction("Download", "ProductName")

Comment: No, sorry I checked. It's `RedirectToAction("Index", "Download")`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25697/discussion-between-mark-oreta-and-alberto)