# How to do the route mapping for this case

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a solution, and it contains two projects. They are both MVC 3 projects.

Project A is the default (start up) one.

Project B is the second one.

They both have controllers and views.

**Example:**

Project A has something like /Home/Index

Project B has something like /Admin/Login

The question is how to write the mapping? When I type in the URL of /Admin/Login, I would like to see the page. Currently I have 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Let the normal routing be there in your global.asax and you can have a controller called "AdminController" to do all your admin tasks.

**2)** Create an Area Called "Admin and have your relevant controllers and views there.

Your default items(Non admin features) can stay in the root level controllers/views.

I would prefer to do the second option of area because it would keep my project clean as it grows. I would like to do a logical seperation of files.

Answer (score 1):

I *sense* that you wish to include /admin from project B into project A.
Have a look at this: [How to reuse Areas, Controllers, Views, Models, Routes in multiple apps or websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656843/how-to-reuse-areas-controllers-views-models-routes-in-multiple-apps-or-websi)

Comment: So basically, the suggestion is create area, instead of create a whole new project?

Comment: You mention that You have Admin in another project. The only way to access Admin from a deployment of Project A is what i suggest above (areas or not). You only need Areas if you wish to have deeper urls. E.g. /Admin/News/{action}/{id}.