# Visual Studio 2013 how to build my project to dll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I am studying .NET for my school project.

I have to compile and make install package to submit my project.

I used install shield to build install package

However, when I installed to another laptop, I can see all the my project files( C# and VB.NET) files are in app folder where is under the  "**program file**" folder

What I understand about building package and compiling project,  VS will create dll files in order to make runable application.(and store in the bin folder)

Therefore, I was trying to check some of resources to convert my project to dll file

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KR038AzJp4I

[Convert a completed project to a DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536140/convert-a-completed-project-to-a-dll)

However, when I switch project type to **Windows form Application**  to **Class library** type, then project started to compile that there is no way to access form files..
for example, if I want to access one element of form from other classes then , compiler started to complain it...

> ```
> Public Sub Init_frmMain_Load()
>     frmMain.ADDRESS.Visible = ref_c.t
>     frmMain.ZIP_WCDMA.Visible = ref_c.t
>
> End Sub
> ```

I am not really sure how to build my project to dll files...

Comment: DLLs are typically helpers with classes in them to provide various services which are called from a Main app, but they cant be run themselves.

Comment: Hi Plutonix: Thanks for helping me. I have a question. If I make application without private dll files(like third party dll files , then all the C# and VB.NET files will be in app folders in "program file" ?(after install app to other laptop or pc)

Comment: For the InstallShield package, you did select / include the *output* of building your project, right? It sounds like instead you told InstallShield to deploy your source.

Comment: Hi Crashmstr// Thanks for helping me.. I am looking for select/include the output of building part from option, but I am not really sure where it is.. can you help me to find it ?