# How do I convert a .NET core project from a web application type to a class library type?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

A .NET Core (dotnet core) project I am working on came with a bunch of class libraries as web projects. They have web.configs, launchSettings.json, etc... I am using VS 2015.

I have compared the projectname.xproj file to class library projectname.xproj files and it has not jumped out at me what the difference is.

I tried removing the web.config and deleting the launchSettings.json file. That didn't do it. I also deleted these property groups from the xproj file that seem to indicate that :

```
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <ProduceOutputsOnBuild>True</ProduceOutputsOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <ProduceOutputsOnBuild>True</ProduceOutputsOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

[This is the correct question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546979/how-to-convert-web-application-project-to-class-library-project) for doing the same thing in old csproj files.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? .NET Core project is meant to be a web application type

Comment: @FailedUnitTest umm... I think that would be an ASP.NET Core project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I overlooked part of the xproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet.Web\Microsoft.DotNet.Web.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```

Just has to change to:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
```